# What is a spike in Tetr.io?

Tags: terminology, tetr.io

I play Tetr.io a lot.

If I send a large amount of garbage, it shows a number, followed by “spike”. What is a spike?

I have found nothing, here on the Arqade, or on Google; just videos of people doing spikes.

Edit: As of 28/09/2021, due to the [6.1.0](https://tetr.io/about/patchnotes/#chlog_6_1_0) update, the UI has been updated so that the word "spike" no longer appears on the side of the board. Instead, when doing a spike, the garbage number simply appears larger and has a flashing animation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a *spike* in Tetr.io is just a name to tell when you get enough garbage to send, to make you understand that you will launch a good amount of it.

Here's a table chart from [Tetr.io wiki](https://tetris.wiki/TETR.IO) with its' legend :

[image: Chart for spikes in Tetr.io from the wiki]

> An illustration of the combo table in use, as well as an explanation of the "B2B Chaining" mechanic. Yellow cells indicate the attack shown is strong enough to cause a "spike", red cells indicate that the garbage sent would be enough to cause a topout if garbage is not countered, and purple cells indicate an attack which is large enough to cause a "spike KO"

As you can see, a *spike* appears when a combo grows large enough, so I don't think there's more about this (plus I didn't found anything more about this term on the wiki or anywhere else).

---

It's still important to differentiate combo and spike, as the first one is the count of successive attacks, and the latter is the total amount of garbage pilled up from all these successive attacks.

[This is a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJe7hL33dLM) from a theknightD2 comment, where we can clearly see the combo count going from 1 to 1, while the spike goes up from different values due to the different attacks performed.

Comment: Yeah but the spike numbers were like 50 spike while combo was at 13. Also spike numbers go from 33 spike to 37 spike. https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=sJe7hL33dLM
(Note: I am not wombotize)

Comment: @theknightD2 The fact that the spike was at 50 while the combo was only at 13 is because the combo is just a counter of how many attack you made in a row, while the spike is the sum of all garbage sent from these attacks. I don't really understand what you mean by "Also spike numbers go from 33 spike to 37 spike", could you be clearer?

Comment: Instead of going from 33 spike to 34 spike, after doing another combo, it jumped to 37 spike.

Comment: @theknightD2 yes, because spike represents the total score of the combo instead of the combo counter. Say, your combo is at 14 and you have a spike of 33 (these values are totally random, don't mind them too much). If your next combo sends 4 garbage, your combo will go from 14 to 15 because you did another one, while your spike will go from 33 to 37, adding the garbage send by the combo to the sum of the combos' garbage. Is it clearer like this?

Comment: Yes. Thank you! (Note: to the person who is going to flag this comment because I said thank you, I wanted to respond to @Zoma.)

Comment: @theknightD2 You're welcome ^^ I will edit my answer to include an explanation to differentiate combo and spike.